# How can I Upload File on Amazon Glacier through web application?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I am trying to create a web application which can upload files to amazon glacier. 
I have created web UI.

I am able to upload a file by giving file path if I run my program locally.

But I am unable to do it if I deploy my application on server. I am getting below exception:

"com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to compute hash for file: "POST /dropbox/v1/documents/old/xyz/upload?filepath=E:\Test.txt HTTP/1.1" 400 34 174 174"

I have deployed application on amazon EC2.

Can anyone please help me? is there any easy way to get rid of this issue? 
plz help me..

```
ArchiveTransferManager atm = new ArchiveTransferManager(client,credentials);
String vaultName = "xyz";
String filePathUpload = "E:/bkp1/New Text Document.txt"

UploadResult result1 = atm.upload(vaultName, filePathUpload, new File(filePathUpload));
```

Comment: What error message are you getting? Do you have some code you could post?

Comment: Hi Efeit, i have updated my post with the error I am getting

Comment: Thanks for the addition, I think seeing how you've formatted your request will help to solve your problem. Are you using [something like this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/uploading-an-archive-single-op-using-java.html) or an [Archive POST](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/api-archive-post.html)? Any code we can see?

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response, I am using first link that u have provided.. exactly the same code

Comment: Does the file exist at that location on the server?

Comment: no this doesn't exist on the server. this file is in my local machine.